# How to stop dogs from urinating on my entrance?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I don't have any pets, but people in my neighborhood walk their dogs in my street. In doing so, the dogs urinate on the wall just outside our front door. This is very annoying because it stains the (white!) porous wall in a very obvious and ugly way, and there's plenty of grass and wall literally one meter away. I'm trying not to get mad at the perpetrators but it's beyond me how dog owners can be so inconsiderate. I mean, it's *right next to my front door!*

I haven't "caught anyone in the act" but it's probably futile (or even counterproductive!) to put up a sign. So I have to find a solution that will repel the dogs, not the owners.

**How can I prevent dogs from peeing on that spot?**

Google results suggest things like **vinegar, bleach, citronella,** as well as some special sprays that probably aren't available in my country. **Do those methods work?** I'd rather not try out stuff that might cause more damage than what's already there.

Answer (score 3):

Part of what's causing the repeat visits (and marking behavior) is the lingering scent of other dogs' 'calling cards'. You'll have to block that, first; then put counter-scents in place.

Is this a wall that can be painted? If so, look for something called Kills (or Kilz, I think the spelling changes from country to country) to cover the wall and lock the urine-scent behind it. I've seen it in white and clear. First, thoroughly clean the wall as thoroughly as possible with bleach (or something similar that will not damage the wall), prepare it for painting (let it dry thoroughly), apply Kills/Kilz according to the directions, and wait for the sealant to cure. Then repaint the wall with its normal color.

After you've gotten rid of as much old scent as you can, and locked the rest behind an impermeable barrier, you can add something around the area (say, just in front of the wall) that discourages the dogs from visiting that wall. Check with a veterinarian to see what locally-available products/methods they would recommend, for olfactory discouragement.

Comment: Before painting the wall, I'd try using something like Nature's Miracle to get out the smell.

Comment: The wall is natural stone, so unfortunately painting is  not an option.

Comment: Still a good option for others, however. Worth remembering that the answer could apply to other structures for other people looking to solve a similar issue.

Comment: Sealing...still might be. Depends on the stone, on the neighborhood regulations, etc. Ask if the person knows about cleaning and protecting natural-stone white walls of the type near your home.